# How to set the value of an enum in java bean using jsp:setProperty action tag?

Tags: java, jsp, enums, jsp-tags

I am trying to populate bean properties in a JSP using `jsp:setProperty` action tag but getting `NullPointerException`.

Is this type of enum property setting even supported by `JSP`?

**AddressType.java**

```
public enum AddressType {
    BILLING, 
    SHIPPING
}
```

**Address.java**

```
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private int addressId;
    private AddressType addressType = AddressType.BILLING;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    //some more code 
}
```

**Setting bean property**

```
<jsp:useBean id="shippingAddress" class="com.ministore.domain.Address" scope="page">
    <jsp:setProperty name="addressType" property="firstName" value="<%= AddressType.SHIPPING %>"/>
</jsp:useBean>
```